# Splunk - Pie chart Drilldown

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am using below Splunk Query to generate pie chart onto my Dashboard

```
index=A (“searchText1” OR “search”Text2) 
| eval split=if(match(_raw, “.*searchText1*”), “count1”, “count2”) 
| chart count by split
```

I want Splunk drill down for searchText1 / searchText2 based on the area that user clicks on pie chart. Please suggest.

P.S. $click.value$ is not working. The click.value is giving count1 / count2.. What i need is searchText1 / searchText2 here..

Answer (score 1):

Use `$click.name$` to drilldown using the field name.
If that doesn't get the desired results, try `$click.value2$`.
See the Visualization manual at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.1.1/Viz/PanelreferenceforSimplifiedXML#Predefined_drilldown_tokens for other available tokens.